# How to use commands (what work well by Bash) on zsh

Tags: bash, macos, zsh, macos-sierra

When I use default Bash on macOS Sierra 10.12.2, I run command

```
mvn -v
```

it return

```
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T23:41:47+07:00)
Maven home: /Users/donhuvy/Documents/program_files/apache-maven-3.3.9
Java version: 1.8.0_112, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_112.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.12.2", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

Then, I use zsh

```
zsh --version
zsh 5.2 (x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0)
```

I try

```
mvn -v
```

the result is

```
zsh: command not found: mvn
```

How to use old commands (works well on default Bash) with zsh?

(I saw that: If I use Bash before, run `mvn -v` it works. After that, then I run `exec zsh`, type `mvn -v`, it works. But problem is, how to at the first time, with zsh, I run command `mvn -v` success?)

Comment: This isn't really due to a difference between bash and zsh; you have some critical environment setup (like additions to `PATH`) in a bash init file like ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login or possibly ~/.bashrc. You either need to replicate that in e.g. ~/.zprofile, or do something like move it to ~/.profile and then source that from both ~/.bash_profile and ~/.zprofile, or ... well, it depends on exactly what that environment setup is.

Comment: I copied the content of `~/.bashrc` to `~/.zprofile`, then restart computer. It doesn't work.